# Does `if` work only in combination with `else` in Series.apply(lambda x)?

Tags: pandas

I'm getting a `SyntaxError` for:

```
housing['Lot Area'].apply(lambda x: x + 50000 if x > 20000)
```

When I add `else`, the code runs fine:

```
housing['Lot Area'].apply(lambda x: x + 50000 if x > 20000 else x)
```

Does `if` only work in combination with `else` here? I'd like to increment `x` with 50000 only if `x > 20000` -- otherwise I'd like `x` to remain unchanged. I find the `else` part a bit redundant here. Besides the first question before, is there any way to write this code without the `else` part?

Comment: the `else` is needed because that's a `ternary` operator http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on your description , even `apply` is not need here

```
housing.loc[housing['Lot Area']>20000,'Lot Area']+=50000
```

Comment from Alex :

***if the if statement resolves to False for a value, then apply() doesn't return and just lets the value in the Series as it is***

Comment: Nice, this is great! Any input for the `if` -`else` part?

Comment: @Alex If should always come with else to complete the logic here

Comment: I guess the confusing part comes from the fact that `if` can be used as a standalone statement in Python. My expectation here was that if the `if` statement resolves to `False` for a value, then `apply()` doesn't return and just lets the value in the `Series` as it is. Now that I think more about this, I realize that this expectation might not be justified. Tx for the input!

Comment: @Alex without the `else` clause, python can't decide the default value you want return. Should it be `x`? `None` ? `0`? etc

Comment: @Wen, I accepted this as a correct answer. If you find some time, I think it'd be great if you added a brief answer to the first question as well, which was "Does `if` only work in combination with `else` here?". I know we already discussed this in the comments section, but it'd probably be better to make it readily available to people coming from searching engines.

Comment: @Alex man feel free to modify the answer , And I think the explanation you provided from comment is well address the problem

Answer (score 1):

you're getting a `SyntaxError` because you are typing invalid syntax. the ternary operator must be used like

```
expression if bool else other_expression
```